# Error in inclusion of Ember View, says its not a class of View

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, emblem.js

I am trying to display a view using ember, emblem, and ember-cli. Seems like this is a no brainer and while I'm new to Ember I cannot seem to get this working:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.8.1
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.12
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.1
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

Ember View:

```
`import Ember from 'ember'`

CalloutView = Ember.View.extend(
  templateName: 'callout'
  )
`export default CalloutView`
```

Emblem Template:

```
h1 Test Content
```

Emblem Index Template:

```
CalloutView
```

## Error from Console:

[image]
I'm using the Ember generator to create this view...I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

The Emblem documentation hasn’t been updated for Ember 1.8, though there’s a [pull request documenting this](https://github.com/machty/emblem-site/pull/16/files#diff-2d770495a596884c25a4601d8cbea520R311). Including a view has changed. Try this, assuming your view lives at `app/views/callout.coffeescript`:

```
=view 'callout'
```

I tried it in an ember-cli application and it worked.